# How to change the font used in the BizTalk script functoid?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'd like to change the font that is used inside the script functoid to a monospaced variant. This should make the inline code more readable.

Changing the Environment font doesn't change the font used in the functoid. And the available BizTalk options only influence the font used in the XSD nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to inline script, you can reference external Assemblies where the code is managed in the full Visual Studio.

Comment: I prefer to not use external assemblies for small scripts. But this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inline scripting functoids are a pain to work with for this reason.  You can take Johns-305 suggestion, but that might be overkill if it's a simple functoid (and will require compiling your library and restarting Visual Studio when signatures or methods change).

What I tend to do here for functoid scripts is edit them in an external editor (Notepad++ or Visual Studio) and then copy and paste them.  Unfortunately, you don't even have an easy way to select all the text (Ctrl+A) doesn't work.  You have to use the cursor and mouse/keyboard to do it.

Comment: I edit my inline code in Visual Studio too, this also gives me the chance to build some unit tests for it as well. I just don't like having to copy inline code somebody else typed to be able to properly read it. But I guess I'll just have to get used to it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to change the font in the Scripting Functoid.